# Running extundelete on root Linux partition

Tags: linux

I need to run extundelete on a ext4 Linux root partition but it warns that the partition should be unmounted. Of course the origram itself is installed on the same partition that is goiung to scan for deleted files.

What's the solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use extundelete on the root filesystem, you have to boot the server from installation/rescue media. You will also need a second disk to store recovered files, otherwise you risk destroying the very files you intend to save.

All in all, it's easiest to just restore the files from backup.

Comment: What I have, is a NetInstall CD. Do I need to download and burn complete CentOS DVD?